# What does each emoji represent in this retelling of Dune?

Tags: dune, object-identification

In August 2016, actor Kyle MacLachlan [tweeted](https://www.cnet.com/news/kyle-maclachlan-lays-out-entire-plot-of-dune-in-emojis/) the entire plot of Frank Herbert's *Dune* via emoji (MacLachlan played Paul Atreides in the [1984 film adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_(film)) directed by David Lynch).

[image: The plot of Dune, as told by emojis]

While I understand what some of the emojis represent (like the purple worm being a sandworm), I'm unsure about others like the syringe.

What does each of these emoji represent within the plot of Dune?

Comment: @Tim I disagree. This is clearly related to understanding the plot of science fiction work. Also I think it would make for a very poor puzzle as it requires plot knowledge to answer rather than puzzling skills.

Comment: @Tim - as a regular on Puzzling.SE I can say that this would probably **not** be well received there, and actually fits on *this* site very well.

Comment: This has made me lol, and curious.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm going to start cataloguing the meanings of the various emoji.  There are two lines of 14 and a final line of 13.

### Appearances and Meanings

#### Line 1

1. Earth – On Planet Caladan,
2. droplet – where there is plenty of water,
3. ✋ hand – Paul's hand
4. Kaaba – goes into the black box when he is tested by the reverend mother
5. dagger – as she is holding a gom jabbar to his throat.
6. rocket ship – They travel on a space ship
7. desert scene – to Arrakis,
8. ☀ sun – where it is sunny
9. thermometer – and really hot,
10. hot pepper – and the spice
11. 100 – is in everything,
12. no faucet and cup symbol – and water is scarce.
13. ⏳ hourglass with flowing sand – After some time,
14. sunset – the protective shield

#### Line 2

15. new moon – gets disabled,
16. pouting face – and Baron Harkonnen attacks.
17. syringe – Dr. Yueh surgically equips Leto with a poison tooth,
18. screaming face – who exhales the poison,
19. smiling face with horns – but Baron Harkonnen escapes laughing,
20. skull – while Leto’s face is defleshed by the poison and he dies.
21. explosion – The Harkonnens destroy the Atreides forces.
22. moon with face – [first moon]
23. moon without face – In the second moon,
24. mouse – there is a mouse shadow (Muad’Dib).
25. explosion – The craft carrying Paul and Jessica crashes into the desert,
26. figure walking – and they walk,
27. 〰 wave – but rhythmic sounds
28. caterpillar – attract a sand worm.

#### Line 3

29. ⌛ hourglass with most sand on bottom – After some time,
30. man with turban – the Fremen
31. folded hands – conjoin
32. explosion – and fight the Harkonnens.
33. sleeping face – The sleeper
34. figure in bed – lies down, drinks the water of life,
35. flushed face – and awakens.
36. explosion – There is more fighthing
37. caterpillar – with sand worms,
38. explosion – and yet more fighting.
39. fist – There is a mêlée
40. ⚔ crossed swords – with blades (duel with Feyd-Rautha),
41. crown – and Paul becomes emperor.

Comment: I think the "lines" are simple word wrap and don't have meaning.

Comment: @Tim I agree.  I just put them in there to simplify the bookkeeping a tad.

Comment: 26-28 are saying "Walking makes sound that summons the sandworms".

Comment: 35 is an embarrassed or shocked face, not sure how that gets to bleeding eyes. Seems like it's supposed to be a "waking up" implication?

Comment: could hot pepper be spice ?

Comment: @dna I never even considered the hot pepper being spice, but that makes sense here.

Comment: @CreationEdge I don't recall whether it happens in the book, but I have a vivid memory of MacLachlan crying blood after drinking the water of life in the film.